# Haskell list generator 2 parameters

Tags: haskell

```
[(x, y) | x <- ['a'..'z'], y <- ['A'..'Z']]
```

Is there any way to get this result:

```
[(a,A), (b, B), ..]
```

and not this:

```
[(a, A), (a, B), ..]
```

without using any plus function ?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to zip the two lists: `zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z']`.

---

If you use `ZipList`s you can achieve the same with applicative style:

```hs
import Control.Applicative (ZipList)

getZipList $ (,) <$> (ZipList ['a'..'z']) <*>  (ZipList ['A'..'Z'])
[('a','A'),('b','B'), {- the list you wanted -}]
```

(Look at [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) for more details.)

Compare the above with the following

```hs
(,) <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['A'..'Z']
```

which is equivalent to your list comprehension.

We are basically applying the same pattern to "zip lists" which are simply like "normal lists" but with a different dressing.

---

Unfortunately (and I did not know), the list comprehension is truly a "normal list" comprehension, so it does not desugar to the applicative style above, which means that

```hs
[(x, y) | x <- (ZipList ['a'..'z']), y <- (ZipList ['A'..'Z'])]
```

is not valid Haskell.

Comment: If `ZipList` were a monad then the last code snippet would be valid (with `MonadComprehensions`). Alas, it is not, and even if GHC could translate this specific case only using applicatives, it does not.

Comment: I would not bother with `ZipList`, really ever except when deriving via it. If you enable `ParallelListComp` you can write `[ (a, b) | a <- ['a'..'z'] | b <- ['A'..'Z'] ]` but the simplest way is to write `zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z']`.